# Firebase get data based on key from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I got a parent table which is `users` and it has 3 childs in it. Can I access a child's data by just passing an uid? Here is my user structure

[image]

What I tried is

```
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').equalTo(localStorage.getItem('uid')).once('value',snap =>{
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

I get an `null` value everytime. I just want to grab what type of user when logging in so that I can display the appropriate UI for every user. Im just new to firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database structure does not allow the kind of query you are trying to perform.  You can only filter child nodes at one level deep from root node of your query.  The root node here is "users", but your actual user data is two levels deep under it.

If you want to find the type of user given only a UID, you will need a structure that puts **all** users under the same root node:

```
- users
   - {uid}
       - type: "doctors" | "patients" | "secretary"
       - email: ...
       - name: ...
```

Now you can very easily query this for a UID to find out what type it is

```
firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(uid).once('value', ...)
```

Comment: but is it okay sir? they have different fields.

Comment: Why is it not OK?

Comment: i just wondering. But thanks sir for your answer. I will make my db like this

Comment: If i select all the users which are `secretary` type sir, its just the same query right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I suggest reviewing the documentation for details about Realtime Database queries.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data